# PDO â¢/TradeMark - Encoding issue UTF8

Tags: php, pdo, encoding, utf-8

**Database class** [ saved as utf8 ]

---

```
private function Connect()
        {
            $this->settings = parse_ini_file("settings.ini.php");
            $dsn = 'mysql:dbname='.$this->settings["dbname"].';host='.$this->settings["host"].';charset=utf8';
            try 
            {
                # Read settings from INI file, set UTF8
                $this->pdo = new PDO($dsn, $this->settings["user"], $this->settings["password"], array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"));

                # We can now log any exceptions on Fatal error. 
                $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

                # Disable emulation of prepared statements, use REAL prepared statements instead.
                $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

                # Connection succeeded, set the boolean to true.
                $this->bConnected = true;
            }
            catch (PDOException $e) 
            {
                # Write into log
                echo $this->ExceptionLog($e->getMessage());
                die();
            }
        }
```

**core.php** [ file saved as utf8 ]
on top has

---

```
ini_set('default_charset','utf-8');
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

I added a logger for the core class it returns  $param = Item : Item™%204125%20|%20Something

```
public function item_price_check($param){
 $param = str_replace("\"", "", $param);
            $param = str_replace("\"", "", $param);
            $param = str_replace(" ", "%20", $param);
            $param = str_replace("\\", "", $param);
            // $param = json_decode($param);

            $itemDetails = $db->query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE name = :param", array(
                "param" => "" . $param . ""
            ));
 if (empty($itemDetails)) { //no add on
                $get_Price = $this->price_check_url($param);
                //Part responsible for database insert
                $insert    = $db->query("INSERT INTO items(cost,lastupdate,name) VALUES(:cost,:lastupdate,:name)", array(
                    "cost" => $get_Price,
                    "name" => $param,
                    "lastupdate" => time()
                ));
.........
}
```

**cost.php** [ file saved as utf8 ]

---

```
<?PHP
ini_set('default_charset','utf-8');
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
include('lib/core.php');
$db = new Db();
$core = new core();

$core->item_price_check($_GET['item']);
?>

Headers

Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:30
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 28 Oct 2015 11:00:07 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Server:Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.4.44-0+deb7u1
X-XSS-Protection:1 ;mode=block

Query Param string : 
item:Item™ 4125 | Something
```

**Database settings**

---

```
Table :: MyISAM utf8_general_ci
Structure :: name   text    utf8_general_ci
```

Summing up - question

---

Everytime I access the cost.php file with a $_GET containing a trademark sign it will be transformed into the â¢ symbol in database, I think I have done everything properly all is utf8 - connection,files. Do you have any idea what could be wrong here? I tried also in the insert numerous functions htmlentitles, utf8 encode, mb_convert for the $param - but each time it returned a â¢. 
Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Trace the value throughout your app. `echo bin2hex(..)`. ™ should be encoded as `E284A2` at all times (`%E2%84%A2` in the URL). Figure out when it starts deviating from that.

Comment: So all they way up-to the database the string contains E284A2. So what can be done now?

Comment: And suddenly in the database you see "â¢"? How have you confirmed this, how are you checking the contents of the database? Assuming your method of checking is correct, the only explanation is that the *database connection encoding* is for whatever reason not set to `utf8` when you insert the data.

Comment: idea: if `ini_set('default_charset','utf-8');` is set in a php file, and not via server settings, might it be that at the time $_GET gets filled (which as far as I understand it is one of the earliest things that happen) does not know about the config setting ?

Comment: Even added "name" => "".iconv(mb_detect_encoding($param, mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8", $param)."", but still got the same :/

Comment: got myself the answer :) tricky one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is following

I have been using a PDO class [ https://github.com/indieteq/PHP-MySQL-PDO-Database-Class/issues/60 ]

and there is a part

```
public function bind($para, $value){
$this->parameters[sizeof($this->parameters)] = ":" . $para . "\x7F" . $value;
}
```

previously the value was `utf8encode($value)`

Comment: So you were using a broken database adapter which caused the issue...? *facepalm*

Comment: uhm yes :| x10 facepalm what is this x7F besides?

Comment: Looks like some custom bull**** to simply store the key and value. Drop that library, I wouldn't trust it one bit.

Comment: Just plain PDO is pretty good. If you want higher abstraction go with something like Doctrine.